# how to animate following the mouse in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousemove

OK, this works perfectly fine for following my mouse.

```
//
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
  $("#follower").css({
      'top': e.pageY + 'px';
      'left': e.pageX + 'px';
  });
});
//
```

And this works great for animating the mouse to a clicked point

```
//
$(document).click(function(e){
  $("#follower").animate({
      top: e.pageY + 'px';
      left: e.pageX + 'px';
  }, 800);
});
//
```

But I personally feel that logically this SHOULD work! Coming from my point of view as the webscripter. Amd then my question is, how can I make this work. I want the #follower to try and follow my mouse with a dynamic kind of lagging behind feel.

```
//
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
  $("#follower").animate({
      top: e.pageY + 'px';
      left: e.pageX + 'px';
  }, 800);
});
//
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

How about using setInterval and an equation called zeno's paradox:

http://jsfiddle.net/88526/1/

That's the way I usually do it.

As requested, I've included the code in this answer. Given a div with absolute positioning:

CSS:

```
#follower{
  position : absolute;
  background-color : red;
  color : white;
  padding : 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="follower">Move your mouse</div>
```

JS w/jQuery:

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
   mouseX = e.pageX;
   mouseY = e.pageY; 
});

// cache the selector
var follower = $("#follower");
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
    // change 12 to alter damping, higher is slower
    xp += (mouseX - xp) / 12;
    yp += (mouseY - yp) / 12;
    follower.css({left:xp, top:yp});

}, 30);
```

Comment: thanks Zevan, I'm gonna try that right now. If I have trouble with the equation I'll be back :)

Comment: Wow, you did it all for me. You're the man. It might be nice for the community if this answer is posted directly into SO. Would you mind if I edited your answer to include this?

Comment: @Zevan the fiddle appears to be broken.

Comment: @Zevan - strange. It was definitely broken before, must have been something with jsFiddle itself. But you are right, it is working now. :)