# Multiple Divs follow cursor all with variable speeds

Tags: jquery, loops, cursor, move

I've done some research on how to get a div/graphic to follow the cursor - [Resource Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847726/how-to-animate-following-the-mouse-in-jquery) - I am trying to create this effect for multiple divs where each div has it's own random speed where some elements are lagging behind more than others. I have created a JS Fiddle to show the current progress, you can see it kind of works to some extend. But I am hoping to achieve a more dramatic effect than what I currently have.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9w1w89e/2/)

Code HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="following blue"></div>
  <div class="following red"></div>
  <div class="following yellow"></div>
  <div class="following orange"></div>
  <div class="following green"></div>
  <div class="following purple"></div>
  <div class="following pink"></div>
</div>
```

Code JS

```
var mouseX = 0,
    mouseY = 0,
    limitX = 400 - 15,
    limitY = 550 - 15;

$(window).mousemove(function(e) {
    // with the math subtractnig the boundary  
    mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX, limitX);
    mouseY = Math.min(e.pageY, limitY);
});

// cache the selector
var followers = $(".following");
var x_pixels = 0,
    y_pixels = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function() {

    // Loop through each follower to move and have random speeds
    followers.each(function() {
      // Set a max Number to allow for the randomIntFromInterval
      // function to work
      var max = followers.length * 15;
      var min = followers.length;

      x_pixels += (mouseX - x_pixels) / randomIntFromInterval(min, max);
      y_pixels += (mouseY - y_pixels) / randomIntFromInterval(min, max);

    $(this).css({
      left: x_pixels,
      top: y_pixels
    });

  });

 }, 40);

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

Any advice on how to do this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by more dramatic effect?

Comment: So one of the 'followers' may have a longer delay following the cursor than another. In the js fiddle provided, you can see they trail at different speeds but they're still quite similar. I'd like a greater difference in each delay. Has this helped answer your question?

Comment: @JordanS - Would you have any advice on this?

Comment: Should each dot have a it's own speed that's constant? So for example the blue dot is slower than the pink dot always?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e3495jmj/1/ - for example

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e3495jmj/2/ - another way you could compute random. Long story short there are a lot of different effects you could go for...

Comment: @JordanS - This is above and beyond anything I was expecting! That first  iteration of the code is what I was expecting...Then you've came and delivered on the second iteration! Thank you very much for the time piecing this together all together for me! I look forward to answering one of your questions one day haha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with why it isn't too random. First off these calculations are run for each dot every 40ms. This has interesting consequences.

```
x_pixels += (mouseX - x_pixels) / randomIntFromInterval(min, max);
y_pixels += (mouseY - y_pixels) / randomIntFromInterval(min, max);
```

Say the blue dot gets a set of random numbers {1, 4, 7, 8, 4, 3, 10, 6, 6} and the red dot gets a set of random numbers {8, 7, 5, 4, 5, 7, 9, 4, 3}. The problem is the average of these is going to be the same (5.44 and 5.77 respectively). Because the movements are happening so fast they have a little jitter but their bigger movements tend to be the same.

The second problem is that you are using the same x_pixels and y_pixels for each dot. You declare this on top:

```
var x_pixels = 0,
y_pixels = 0;
```

But then you don't ever go get the current value back from the dot. You recycle them by += but each dot shares the same position.

I have two solutions for you as this problem is fairly broad and could be interpreted multiple ways. Both of these solutions address the problems listed above by assigning a friction coefficient that stays with the dot. The first example keeps the random friction for the lifetime of the dot, the second changes the friction coefficient every so often.

[jsfiddle.net/e3495jmj/1](http://jsfiddle.net/e3495jmj/1)  - First solution

[jsfiddle.net/e3495jmj/2](http://jsfiddle.net/e3495jmj/2)  - Second solution

Cheers!

Comment: Really appreciate you taking the time to go into explaining why it didn't work. This is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thank's very much!

Comment: Would you know any reason why the examples you have provided aren't working within Safari? I've `console.log(x_pixels)` and in Chrome it returns a `value`, however in Safari it returns with `NaN`. I wonder why that is?